Vector calculus equality from potential theory
Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics, p. 74, does 2.14 -> 2.16 below as integration by parts. I would like to understand the variational approach in Binney & Tremaine's Galactic Dynamics, p.33:

My question is about first equality in the paragraph above 2.16 after "But..."
Using definitions,
$\nabla \phi = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\textbf{i} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}\textbf{j} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z}\textbf{k};~~\delta \phi = \frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x}\delta x+\frac{\partial \phi}{\delta \dot{x}}\delta \dot{x}~ +~...\text{etc.};~~ \nabla (\delta\phi) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\delta x +\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \dot{x}}\delta \dot{x})~\textbf{i} ~+...\text{etc.}$
It does not seem that dotting $\nabla \phi$ and $\nabla (\delta \phi)$ will give the desired result.

Going backwards, you have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\delta(\nabla\Phi\cdot\nabla\Phi) = \frac{1}{2}\delta\nabla\Phi\cdot\nabla\Phi + \frac{1}{2}\nabla\Phi\cdot\delta\nabla\Phi = \nabla\Phi\cdot\delta\nabla\Phi
$$
thanks to the product rule and symmetry of the dot product. Now, you may check component-wise that the functional differential $\delta$ and the nabla operator $\nabla$ commute $-$ because they contains only partial derivatives, basically $-$, hence $\delta\nabla\Phi = \nabla(\delta\Phi)$ and finally the wanted result.
